# Example of an identity function that's not continuous

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

I was looking at this big list mathoverflow question about common misconceptions: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics specifically as a comment to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/23483) question

something brought up in the comments but not elaborated on was that the identity function is not necessarily continuous. I haven't been able to find anything about it, and I can't think of any examples for this. If anyone could offer some insight on this, I am interested to hear.

Comment: Hmm.  I might be wrong but every epsilon if |x-a| < epsilon... then |x-a| < epsilon.  So I'd have to say that identity is continuou.  Not by definition but trivially certainly.  I might be missing something but...

Comment: And with the answer by fraraad armwood I see how it could be otherwise.  Maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $X=(\mathbb{R}, \textrm{indiscrete topology})$ and $Y=(\mathbb{R}, \textrm{euclidean topology})$. Let $\iota: X \to Y$ be the map given by $\iota(x) = x$. Observe that $\iota^{-1}(\{z\}) = \{z\}$ and $\{z\}$ is closed in $Y$, but not in $X$ since the only closed sets are $\emptyset, \mathbb{R}$ with the indiscrete topology.

Comment: And continuity must map closed to closed?  Is it fair to call these identities if they map to different topologies?

Comment: (1) Yes, prove it! (2) $X \not = Y$, the topologies are different. Their underlying sets are the same, but the structure is different. That's the big thing. We typically don't write $(\mathbb{R}^n, \textrm{euclidean topology})$ since it is understood that we are working with this topology. Of course $X$ given in my example is a very non-sensical space to work with, but with our definitions we can produce ugly spaces with counter-intutitve properties.

Comment: It is not so much mapping closed sets to closed sets. It is that the inverse of every closed set is closed. Also, identities are maps on sets so it is definitely okay that the structures are different.

Comment: @G.Snapsmath: I understood that question to mean inverse image of closed is closed.

Answer (score 5):

Consider two different topologies $ \tau_{1} $, $ \tau_{2} $ on the same set $X$. It can be easily shown (just apply the definition of a continuous map) that the identity map $id_{X}:(X, \tau_{2}) \rightarrow (X, \tau_{1})$ is a continuous function if and only if $\tau_{1} \subseteq \tau_{2}$.

**P.S.:** Note that in the above, the term "identity" map for $id_{X}:id_{X}(x)=x, \ \forall x \in X$ is in fact used only in the set-theoretic sense but not in the topological sense.

Comment: Ahh, you should save the remark you made after the first paragraph and leave it to the OP to ask him/herself when is the identity map going to be continuous then. Great insight though!

Answer (score 2):

Just to give another example in addition to Faraad, you can take the identity from from $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology into $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. These two types of examples are very useful. Every function whose domain has the discrete topology is continuous. in the same way it is "hard" to have a continuous function into the discrete topology. Similarly every function into the trivial (indiscrete) topology is continuous, it is "hard" to have a continuous function from the trivial topology.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute to this discussion with another example.

Let $X_1=C^0([0,1])$ with the norm $\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|\,dx$ and let $X_\infty=C^0([0,1])$ with the norm $\|f\|_\infty=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$. It can be proven that both are normed spaces. They are the same set but endowed with different norms, that is, different topologies.

Let $I_d:X_1\longrightarrow X_\infty$ be the identity mapping, that is, $I_d(f)=f$. Since $I_d$ is a linear operator, we know that continuity is equivalent to boundedness (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator)).

Suppose $I_d$ is bounded. Then there exists $c>0$ such that
$$\|f\|_\infty=\|I_d(f)\|_\infty\leq c\|f\|_1,\ \forall f\in C^0([0,1]).$$

However, let us consider $f_n:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the following continuous function

[image]

We can see that
$$n=\|f_n\|_\infty\leq c\|f_n\|_1=\frac{c}{2},\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N},$$
which is an absurd!